# Run-time error: '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, excel

My Client is getting this error but it is running fine on my machine. He is getting error on this line..

ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.Value = "Select Department Category Group"

can you please tell me what is porblem??

Comment: If it's possible, I  think it's better you use the `sheet's name` instead of `ActiveSheet`. So:  `Sheets("YourSheetName").ComboBox1.Value = "Select Department Category Group"`

Comment: thanks for reply but i want to know .... why it is running fine on my machine  but my client is getting error on this line...

Comment: If (for some unknow reason) the Active Sheet changes, the code will not work! But you can't prevent from activating another sheet!

Comment: i agree with you but there is only one sheet in workbook which is active state. so there is no possibility to change sheet while running code.

Comment: how about more than one workbook open?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, It is a drop down type. So, You cannot set value. You should add item as follow:

```
Sheets("sheetname").Shapes("comboname").ControlFormat.AddItem ("Select Department Category Group")
```

Comment: this give me error unable to get dropdown property of worksheet class..  is there versioning issue at client side..

Comment: same error...but i want to know .... why my above code running fine on my machine but my client is getting error on this line

Comment: ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.Value = "Select Department Category Group"   running fine for me but my client is getting error on this line... i just want to know is there any version compatibility  issue??

Comment: Right, It will be. Actually, I think that when running this code, work sheet which has your combo box is not active. So, it shown error. So, you should use as Sheets("sheetname") when indicating your sheet. When I running your code, I also got error. After modify as my answer, It work well.